# how to reduce the distance b/w the column contains 2 column graphs in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Column graph contains 2 column graphs only, then how to reduce the distance b/w bars in highcharts.
I have tried using min and max, but i'm unable to reduce the distance.
i want two column graphs more closer to each other.
I helave tried with below code:
min:0.0,
max: props.months.length - 1.0, and I have tried with pointPadding property as well but didn't work.[image: refere image here]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve it by increasing the `pointRange` property.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bh8yz2ua/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.pointRange